# How to pass data from a Barcode scanner to a Textfield (Flutter)

Tags: flutter, dart, barcode

I am using the 'flutter_barcode_scanner' package and I want to pass some data from the barcode scanner to a `TextField` in the app that I am working on.

I have a `TextEditingController` like this:

```
 var searchController = TextEditingController();
```

And the code I use for the barcode scanner is this:

```
Future<void> scanBarcodeNormal() async {
    String barcodeScanRes;
    try {
      barcodeScanRes = await FlutterBarcodeScanner.scanBarcode('#ff6666', 'Cancel', true, ScanMode.BARCODE);
      print(barcodeScanRes);
    } on PlatformException {
      barcodeScanRes = 'Cihazınız barkod okumayı desteklemiyor.';
    }
    if (!mounted) return;
    setState(() {
      _scanBarcode = barcodeScanRes;
    });
  }
```

I know that I need to change some things in the last part,

```
 if (!mounted) return;
    setState(() {
      _scanBarcode = barcodeScanRes;
    });
```

I want to replace the `setState(() {})` with a code that achieves what I want (Passing the data from the barcode to the TextField.)

I am trying to replace the `setState(() {})` of the barcode scanner with a code that passes the data to TextField.

Comment: `searchController.text = barcodeScanRes`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try replacing this statement

```
setState(() {
  _scanBarcode = barcodeScanRes;
});
```

With this

```
searchController.text  = barcodeScanRes;
```

Gist: https://gist.github.com/SteplerPaulo/cee0e6f03fb8c1b7a5014074f665594b

Comment: Thank you for your answer!
It looks like it fixed the issue but there is one problem.. It says, 'undefined name: mounted'.

Comment: Nice!  Please upvote my answer :) 

In regards to your follow up question, can you update your question with your complete code? But yeah, maybe you could just remove the  ```if (!mounted) return;``` statement if you don't need it

Comment: Sorry, it says 'Thanks for the feedback! You need at least 15 reputation to cast a vote, but your feedback has been recorded.' :(

Thanks again, removing the if statement fixed the issue!